# What would be the best way of recreating this jagged edge?

Tags: modeling, particles

I want to create a rough wooden edge, similar to the top of the wood in this image. I have tried increasing the vertices on the edge and then extending a random number, but it isn't at all convincing.
I haven't used the particle system much, so not sure if that would do it.
I would also like to recreate some of the tiny wooden burs that appear on the flat side of the wood also.
[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Try Luma.Ai or Polycam, if you have the object physically. it can make nice 3D scans

Answer (score 0):

Maybe subdivide the top face and use a *Displace* modifier on Z? You can even pull some faces manually to have some peaks.

[image]